# difference Boolean modifier: put new vertices into their own vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups, boolean-modifier

I have a rectangular prism that I'm cutting letters into using an extruded text mesh and a difference Boolean modifier. I want to put all of the new "texty" vertices created by the modifier into one vertex group. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: did you apply the modifier? can you show some pictures of what you have tried?

Comment: The modifier worked great. I just can't select the vertices I want to select. There are thousands of them. I want to tag the intersection faces for different shading.